# Can a try-catch block in C# handle enter more than one catch block?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have some code like this:

```
try 
{
    doStuff();
}
catch(SpecificException) 
{
    if(e.Message == interestingMessage)
        doOtherStuff();
    else
        throw;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

When the first catch block rethrows its exception, will it be caught by the second catch block?

Comment: When your ran this code, what happened? (in the future, try testing such things yourself - you will get a fast and definite answer).

Comment: Unfortunately "No." is under the minimum answer length. No one can answer. You will need to test it yourself.

Comment: you could try to force an exception and see the output or if you want to make sure just insert return;

Comment: The rethrow does not take place inside the `try` block. Only exceptions thrown inside `try { ... }` can be caught.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, if you rethrow the exception you do it to the method caller.

The if inside `SpecificException` catch would indicates that you need to split that exception into (at least) 2 different types.

Comment: Or the next surrounding `try`/`catch`.